# How do I break up a string without creating malformed HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, parsing, html-parsing

**What I am doing**:

- In NodeJS I am creating an email template by using MustacheJS, using data from an array of JSON objects.
- The text/message that goes in the template can contain text along with basic html tags (such as `b` `p` & `a`).
- Due to limitation of space I need to only show an excerpt of the message. For that I do a word count, and after lets say 20 words (checked by spaces) I truncate the string and append `View more` anchor tag. This links it to the website's post page, that contains the complete post. Something like:

> Hey this is a sample post text `<b>message</b>`. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
>   amit... `<a href="someurl">`View more`</a>`

**The problem:**

During word count and truncation, it is possible that I truncate the string in between an html tag as I am simply calculating words on basis of space. Something like:

> I am sharing a link with you. `<a style="color:`... `<a href="someurl">`View more`</a>`

Now this will break the html.

**Possible solution:**

- Before truncating string, run a regex on it to find all the html tags in it.
- Use `indexOf()` (or some other method) to find starting and ending indices of each tag.
- After word count, get the index where I need to truncate it.
- Now see that if the index intersects with any of the tags region.
- If it does intersect, simply move the truncate index to the start or end of the html tag.

**Question:**

Is there a better way to do this. I don't know what search terms I should be searching on google, to get help with this.

P.S. The code is flexible and I can change the flow if there is a significantly better solution. Also, I am not good with post titles. If you can, please modify it to something that reflects the question.

---

**EDIT:**

This is what I came up with after Alex's answer. Hope it helps someone else:

```
/**
 * Counter: Takes a string and returns words and characters count
 * @param value
 * @returns obj: {
 *      'wordCount': (int),
 *      'totalChars': (int),
 *      'charCount': (int),
 *      'charCountNoSpace': (int)
 *  }
 */
var counter = function(value){
    var regex = /\s+/gi;
    if (!value.length) {
        return {
            wordCount: 0,
            totalChars: 0,
            charCount: 0,
            charCountNoSpace: 0
        };
    }
    else {
        return {
            wordCount: value.trim().replace(regex, ' ').split(' ').length,
            totalChars: value.length,
            charCount: value.trim().length,
            charCountNoSpace: value.replace(regex, '').length
        };
    }
}


/**
 * htmlSubString - Creates excerpt from markup(or even plain text) without creating malformed HTML tags
 * @param markup {string} - Markup/text to take excerpt out of
 * @param limit {int} - Total word count of excerpt. Note that only text (not the html tag) counts as a valid word.
 * @returns {string} - Excerpt
 */
var htmlSubString = function(markup, limit){
    var htmlParser = require("htmlparser2");
    var tagCount = 0;
    var wordCount = 0;
    var excerpt = '';

    function addToExcerpt(type, text, attribs) {
        if ((wordCount >= limit && tagCount == 0) || (tagCount === 1 && type === 'tagOpen' && wordCount >= limit)) {
            return false;
        }
        else if (wordCount < limit || tagCount) {
            if (type === 'text') {
                var wordCountSubString = $scope.counter(text).wordCount;
                if (wordCountSubString + wordCount > limit && tagCount === 0) {
                    var length = limit - wordCount;
                    var wordList = text.trim().split(' ');

                    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                        excerpt += ' ' + wordList[i];
                        wordCount++;
                    }
                } else {
                    wordCount += wordCountSubString;
                    excerpt += text;
                }

            } else if (type === 'tagOpen') {
                excerpt += '<' + text;
                for (var prop in attribs) {
                    excerpt += ' ' + prop + '="' + attribs[prop] + '"';
                }
                excerpt += '>';
            } else if (type === 'tagClose') {
                excerpt += '</' + text + '>';
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    var parser = new htmlParser.Parser({
        onopentag: function (name, attribs) {
            if(wordCount < limit){
                ++tagCount;
                addToExcerpt('tagOpen', name, attribs);
            }
        },
        ontext: function (text) {
            if(wordCount < limit){
                addToExcerpt('text', text);
            }
        },
        onclosetag: function (tagName) {
            if(wordCount < limit || tagCount > 0){
                addToExcerpt('tagClose', tagName);
                --tagCount;
            }
        }
    });

    parser.write(markup);
    parser.end();

    return excerpt;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var wordCountLimit = 20;
var markup = "/* some markup/text */";
var excerpt = htmlSubString(markup, wordCountLimit);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, you'll definitely be able to find some HTML tag matching regular expressions. That said, I don't recommend it. At first you'll be all happy and everything will work just fine. Then tomorrow you'll find a small edge-case. "No worries!" You'll say, as you modify the expression to account for the discrepancy. Then the next day, a new tweak, and a new one, and yet another, etc etc until you can't take it anymore.

I highly recommend you find an already established HTML parsing library. There appears to be quite a few on npm. [This one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmlparser2) seems to be fairly popular.

PS - You did fine with your question. I wish more questions took as much time and provided as much detail :)

Comment: Looking in to the link.

Comment: I think we might have a winner here. Although the cost here is more than regex solution, this method is less prone to errors. I am going to do some benchmarks, and see how much it affects my server, as it needs to send out bunch of emails timely.

Comment: I think the "cost" as it were, would actually be more for you with regular expressions. I've been down that road, trust me ;). Also, I can almost guarantee a properly written parsing library is going to be extremely more performant than regular expressions. That library I linked you even supports parsing streams :D